# Bug in analytical expression of integral containing Abs function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I [came across](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2832912/sum-infty-infty-frac-exp-n21-4n2-in-closed-form/2832965#2832965) a possible bug in Mathematica's evaluation of integrals that I thought I'd share. Consider the code:

```
zmax = 4;
a =  Integrate[Exp[-x^2] Abs[Sin[x]], {x, -z   , z   }] /. z -> zmax
b = NIntegrate[Exp[-x^2] Abs[Sin[x]], {x, -zmax, zmax}]
a - b
```

If `zmax` is smaller than $\pi$ it evaluates close to $0$ (to the precision limit) while for `zmax` greater than $\pi$ it evaluates to $-4.50908\cdot 10^{-6}$ (which happens to be roughly $4\cdot \int_{\pi}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\sin(x){\rm d}x$). The condition $z< \pi$ is not listed in Matematica's (11.2.0.0) analytical expression for the integral `a` above:

```
ConditionalExpression[( Sqrt[\[Pi]] (2 Erfi[1/2] - Abs[Sin[z]] Csc[z] (Erfi[1/2 - I z] + Erfi[1/2 + I z])))/(2 E^(1/4)), Re[z] >= 0 && Im[z] == 0]
```

Anybody knows why this happens? If I were to guess, based on the result above, it looks like Mathematica uses the symmetry to rewrite the integral as $2$ times the integral over $[0,z]$ and then for some reason removes the absolute value over $\sin(x)$ (which is allowed only if $z<\pi$), but forgets to mention it.

Comment: @ Winther Just for completeness and because you don't mention where you "came across" this problem. Here's my guess: it was my painful answer to a question in MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2832912/sum-infty-infty-frac-exp-n21-4n2-in-closed-form/2832965#2832965

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze Yes. I added the link to the question.

Comment: @ Winther: the discontinuity of the antiderivative at z = n pi was first pointed out by Mariusz Iwaniuk in trying to find the error in my answer. A correct formula for the integral taking into account the jumps in the antiderivatives was given there independently by him and myself.

Answer (score 2):

There is a discontinuity in the antiderivative:

```
Plot[(Sqrt[π] (2 Erfi[1/2] - 
    Abs[Sin[z]] Csc[z] (Erfi[1/2 - I z] + Erfi[1/2 + I z]))) / (2 E^(1/4)),
 {z, 3, 3.25}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If a concrete limit greater than `Pi` in magnitude is supplied, `Integrate` is able to account for the discontinuity; otherwise the general formula is used that is not valid:

```
Integrate[Exp[-x^2] Abs[Sin[x]], {x, -4, 4}] // N
(*  0.848877 + 0. I  *)

Integrate[Exp[-x^2] Abs[Sin[x]], {x, -z, z}, 
   Assumptions -> -z < x < z] /. z -> 4 // N
(*  0.848873 + 0. I  *)
```

The use of `Assumptions` merely removes the `ConditionalExpression` from the result:

```
Integrate[Exp[-x^2] Abs[Sin[x]], {x, -z, z}]
(*
  ConditionalExpression[(
   Sqrt[π] (2 Erfi[1/2] - 
      Abs[Sin[z]] Csc[z] (Erfi[1/2 - I z] + Erfi[1/2 + I z])))/(2 E^(1/4)), 
   C[1] ∈ Integers && z >= 2 π C[1] && C[1] >= 0]
*)
```

The expression gives the erroneous result `0.848873` for `C[1] -> 0`; otherwise it is undefined.

Further, since `Integrate` can handle the discontinuity in the concrete case, one is left wondering whether the condition that `Abs[z] < Pi` could be added to the `ConditionalExpression`.

Comment: @ Michael E2: Not only at z = pi, the antiderivative has jumps at z = k pi (k=1,2,3..). You might wish to see the original discussion at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2832912/sum-infty-infty-frac-exp-n21-4n2-in-closed-form/2832965#2832965. Here the correct expression for the integral is given by correcting for the jumps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Interesting that it handles it correctly for a concrete input. The fact that it's discontinuous means it's not a correct antiderivative (an antiderivative is continuous) so the conditions $z<\pi$ should (not just could) be added to result IMO.

Comment: @ Micheal E2 You will remember that we had this discussion several times before. I'd like to suggest now that Mathematica gives a warning to the user. Something like "Warning: the result of this integral may be incorrect in the case where the antiderivative contains spurious jumps. Please check for jumps and correct them manually (using Limit)." Such a warning should be issued in cases where there are "conspicious" functions in the integrand, like Abs etc. What do you think?

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze Yes, but is it really that important? We have seen many times that `Integrate` struggles with even one discontinuity in the integral.

Answer (score 2):

OK when the right syntax (`RealAbs` instead of `Abs` ) is used:

```
zmax = 4;a = Integrate[Exp[-x^2] RealAbs[Sin[x]], {x, -z, z}] /. z -> zmax
```

> ```
> (-I Sqrt[π] Erf[4 + I/2] + 2 Sqrt[π] Erfi[1/2] + 
>  Sqrt[π] Erfi[1/2 + 4 I] - 2 Sqrt[π] Erfi[1/2 - I π] - 
>  2 Sqrt[π] Erfi[1/2 + I π])/(2 E^(1/4))
> ```

```
b = NIntegrate[Exp[-x^2] RealAbs[Sin[x]], {x, -zmax, zmax}]
```

> 0.84887725359944

```
a - b
```

> 1.21014*10^-14 + 0. I

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would not say RealAbs is the right syntax and Abs is wrong, both should give correct results! But based on this it seems RealAbs is safer than Abs and should be the recommended choice for real integrals which is something I'll keep in mind

Comment: @Winter: Your claim "I would not say RealAbs is the right syntax and Abs is wrong, both should give correct results! " does not correspond to reality. For example, compare the results of Integrate[RealAbs[x],x] and Integrate[Abs[x],x].

Comment: My comment was not on what Mathematica outputs, but what is mathematically correct. Abs[x] and RealAbs[x] are equivalent when x is real.

Comment: It’s perfectly fine that using one function does not give an answer while the other one does (as in your example). It’s not fine that both choices gives an answer which disagree with each other. That is a bug.

Comment: @ Winther Sorry for intervening, but - as I have no Version 11 - could you please just repeat your cases with RealAbs instead of Abs, and also calculate the antiderivative with RealAbs?

Comment: @ Winter I did it in the Wolfram cloud (thanks to the hint of Mariusz). The result is that with RealAbs[] Matematica refuses to calculate an antiderivative but returns the input unchanged. That may be the reason that numerical results can be correct, see my paradoxial conclusion in my solution (extended comment) here.

Comment: Hmm, I thought that was the first thing I tried... +1

Comment: Again, it seems that in order to get a valid result one must look for a means to aviod that Mathematica is able to calculate an antiderivative,

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer but an extended comment.

**Summary**

The results of the study below can be summarized as follows

1) the root cause of problems (i.e. discontinuities in the antiderivative) is the apperance of `f[x]Abs[]` in the integrand when `f[x]!=const.` (The EDIT in the end done afterwards points to the necessity of `Abs[Sin[x]]` or `Abs[Cos[x]]`) to get in trouble.

2) The antiderivative is returned only if the integral is two-sided AND symmetric.

3) As the one sided integral does not have the numerical problems pointed out in this OP we conclude tentatively (and boldly) that the numerical results are correct if Mathematica can NOT find an anitidrivative. Sounds a little paradoxial ...

4) Replacing `Sin[x]` by `Cos[x]` gives an antiderivative with clearly visible jumps

**Study**

Let us consider some related cases and see if there are problems or not.

Case (a1) replacing the Exp[-x^2] factor by unity: no problems

```
zmax = 4; 
a = Integrate[ Abs[Sin[x]], {x, -z, z}] /. z -> zmax ; 
b =  NIntegrate[ Abs[Sin[x]], {x, -zmax, zmax}] ; 
a - b

-2.44249*10^-15
```

Hence the problem is not due to Abs[] alone.

The antiderivative in this case

```
Integrate[ Abs[Sin[x]], {x, -z, z}]

Out[22]= ConditionalExpression[
 4 IntegerPart[z/\[Pi]] - 
  2 (-1 + Cos[\[Pi] FractionalPart[z/\[Pi]]]) Sign[
    FractionalPart[z/\[Pi]]], z \[Element] Reals]
```

despite its apperance seems to have no jumps.

Case (a2) Replacing Exp[-x^2] by x^2 : problems

```
zmax = 4; 
a =  Integrate[x^2 Abs[Sin[x]], {x, -z, z}] /. z -> zmax ; 
b =  NIntegrate[x^2 Abs[Sin[x]], {x, -zmax, zmax}] ; 
a - b

-31.4784
```

The reason is already known: the antideriative

```
Integrate[x^2 Abs[Sin[x]], {x, -z, z}]

ConditionalExpression[
 2 (-2 + Abs[Sin[z]] (2 z - (-2 + z^2) Cot[z])), 
 Re[z] >= 0 && Im[z] == 0]
```

has jumps at z = k pi.

This is perhaps the most elementary example exhibiting the problems here.

Case (a3) Replacing Exp[-x^2] by Abs[x]: problems

```
zmax = 4; a = 
 Integrate[Abs[x] Abs[Sin[x]], {x, -z, z}] /. z -> zmax ; b = 
 NIntegrate[Abs[x] Abs[Sin[x]], {x, -zmax, zmax}] ; a - b

Out[21]= -12.5664
```

The antiderivative

```
Integrate[Abs[x] Abs[Sin[x]], {x, -z, z}]

ConditionalExpression[-2 Abs[Sin[z]] (-1 + z Cot[z]), 
 Re[z] >= 0 && Im[z] == 0]
```

has jumps at z = k pi.

Case (b) the one-sided integral: no problems

```
zmax = 4; 
a =  Integrate[Exp[-x^2] Abs[Sin[x]], {x, 0, z}] /. z -> zmax ; 
b =  NIntegrate[Exp[-x^2] Abs[Sin[x]], {x, 0, zmax}] ; a - b

6.05072*10^-15 + 0. I
```

This is surprising (at least for me).

It is intesting that neither for the one sided integral

```
Integrate[Exp[-x^2] Abs[Sin[x]], {x, 0, z}]
```

nor for the indefinite integral

```
Integrate[Exp[-x^2] Abs[Sin[x]], x]
```

nor for the unsymmtric two sided integral, e.g.

```
Integrate[E^-x^2 Abs[Sin[x]], {x, -z, 2 z}]
```

Mathematica provides an antiderivative but returns the input unchanged.

For comparison we repeat here the antidrivative of the two sided integral:

```
Integrate[Exp[-x^2] Abs[Sin[x]], {x, -z, z}]

Out[30]= ConditionalExpression[(
 Sqrt[\[Pi]] (2 Erfi[1/2] - 
    Abs[Sin[z]] Csc[z] (Erfi[1/2 - I z] + Erfi[1/2 + I z])))/(
 2 E^(1/4)), Re[z] >= 0 && Im[z] == 0]
```

**EDIT 30.08.18 15:15**

*case "truncated sin"*

This case makes me wonder if my conclusions are correct.

Taking a "truncated sine" `x(1 - (x/\[Pi])^2)` instead of Sin[x] gives an antideriative without jumps:

```
Integrate[E^-x^2 Abs[x (1 - (x/\[Pi])^2)], {x, -z, z}]

Out[53]= ConditionalExpression[(
 E^-z^2 (1 - \[Pi]^2 + E^z^2 (-1 + \[Pi]^2) + z^2))/\[Pi]^2, 
 0 < Re[z] < \[Pi] && Im[z] == 0]
```

*Cos instaed of Sin*

If we replace `Sin[x]` by `Cos[x]` there is no hiding of tiny jumps anymore

```
Integrate[E^-x^2 Abs[Cos[x]], {x, -z, z}]

Out[66]= ConditionalExpression[(
 I Sqrt[\[Pi]]
   Abs[Cos[z]] (Erfi[1/2 - I z] - Erfi[1/2 + I z]) Sec[z])/(
 2 E^(1/4)), \[Pi] + z + Conjugate[z] <= 0]
```

The graph is

[image]

The jumps are at the zeroes of `Cos[]`, i.e. at `z= (2 k + 1) \[Pi]/2`.

And the jump sizes are

```
j[k_] := -((
  I Sqrt[\[Pi]] (Erfi[1/2 - ((2 k + 1) I \[Pi])/2] - 
     Erfi[1/2 + ((2 k + 1) I \[Pi])/2]))/(2 E^(1/4)))
```

The sequnce of j[k] is extremely slowing decreasing

```
Table[N[j[k], 30], {k, 0, 4}] // Chop

{
-1.39137915049102862583968181080, 
-1.380388447038392527457349263471, 
-1.380388447043142974773415246738, 
-1.380388447043142974773415246726, 
-1.380388447043142974773415246726
}
```

*Case explizit numbers for integration limits*

Explizit numbers instead of a variable z leads to numerically correct results.

Example is the comparison of a sum with its integral representation

Let

```
sN = 
 NSum[Exp[-n^2]/(1 - 4 n^2), {n, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 20]

Out[210]= 0.7522978984722431448
```

Then the sum is increasingly well approximated by the integral

```
Table[N[Sqrt[\[Pi]]/2 Integrate[E^-x^2 Abs[Sin[x]], {x, -n, n}] - sN, 
   20], {n, 1, 6}] 

{-0.22995897048993183416 + 0.*10^-21 I,
 -0.0058037201019733100 +  0.*10^-23 I,
 -3.67451669256173*10^-6 + 0.*10^-26 I,
 -1.99280197442*10^-8 + 0.*10^-28 I,
 -2.2294568*10^-12 + 0.*10^-32 I,
 -6.9*10^-18 + 0.*10^-37 I}
```

Comment: You can try for free `MMA 11.3` in wolfram cloud: https://develop.wolframcloud.com/   only you must sign-in.
I use because they have a better computer than mine->28 Cores 32 GB RAM :). Limitation is time(or another things, well I don't know) to use,about 5 minutes max.

Comment: @ Mariusz Iwaniuk  Thanks for the hint. It works fine.